# how to update kendo grid when sql table updated?

Tags: kendo-grid

I called one sql table "CarDetails" in more than two jsp's and i want to when from 1.jsp are updated "CarDetails" table then at that time update kendo grid from 2.jsp.

thank you.

Comment: what did you try till now and where is the code for that?

Comment: @saurabh: hello sourabh I will try to automatically update my kendo grid data when changes occurred in sql table and i used one sql table in two different jsp.

Comment: when i updated sql table from one.jsp then at that time updated data will show in kendo grid table from two.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh Really forget. I Found this question 2 year ago but now I updating my solution.I am littlest upset for no one reply this question answer yet. Btw I updated my answer self.

I used web socket for communication between two jsp files. I wrote server and client web socket for notify to another jsp. I also able to send parameter with web socket. Following link I used for the implementing web socket.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

And I used web socket from 2 year Its working seamless.